# URl rewrite httpd.ini multiple query string parameters

Tags: asp.net, iis, apache

Helo,

I have a problem when rewriting my url with multiple Query String Parameters

```
RewriteRule /romeojuliette-namur/\?guid=(.+)$               /page/RomeoJuliette/Default.aspx?guid=$1&region=namur [I,L]
```

It doesn't recognize the second paramter region. Ho do I solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by switching the order of the paramaters. But that is probably not the finest solution.

```
RewriteRule /romeojuliette-namur/\?guid=(.+)$               /page/RomeoJuliette/Default.aspx?region=namur&guid=$1 [I,L]
```